# Get top scorer(s) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple table:

```
ID    Score
1     90
2     85
3     96
4     96
5     73
```

I want to get the top scorer(s) so I used max function:

```
select max(s.score) as score,
    s.id
from student_score as s
```

result:

```
score    id
96       1
```

The problem is, there are two top scorers, how am I going to get all top scorers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subquery gets the maximum score from table `student_score` which the result will be used to compare on `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM student_score a
WHERE Score = 
(
    SELECT MAX(Score)
    FROM student_score
)
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f20f9/3)

Comment: Kabayan, actually, my table wasn't that simple, it's a result of another subquery, how can I reuse a subquery in MySQL? Like a virtual table or whatever it is called? Just give me a hint I can then search it myself.

Comment: do you mean `VIEW`? kabayan you can still join the subquery on your main query. :D

Comment: no, I don't want to create  view, what I'm looking for is like the "with" of SQL Server. student_score is actually a subquery, I don't want to do a copy-paste, it's ugly :)

Comment: unfortunately, `MySQL` does not support `common table expression`. and `VIEW` is horrible in `MySQL`. the only thing you will do is to have `Subquery`...

Comment: Aside from your solution, can you think of another way to get it done without using student_score twice?

Comment: take a look at my answer, it's a little more reusable version, don't know if it'll help you

Answer (score 3):

```
select s.score, s.id
from student_score as s
where
    s.score in 
    (
        select max(t.score)
        from student_score as t
    )
```

If you want your subquery to be reusable, try this

```
select s.score, s.id, m.score
from student_score as s
    cross join (select max(t.score) as score from student_score as t) as m
where s.score = m.score
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f20f9/17)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Use your query as a sub query to select the score from the actual table

```
select * 
from  student_score 
where score in
 (
    select max(score)
    from   student_score )
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f20f9/4)

Answer (score 1):

Max is an aggregate function and returns only one row. The easiest would be to issue a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM student_score
WHERE score = (
    SELECT MAX(score) FROM student_score
)
```

Make sure you have an index on score if you have a lot of rows.