# MySQL add score column to SELECT high scores query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database named `users` that contains the following:

```
userid   name     highscore
0        sam      20
1        james    39
2        jack     3
3        harry    46
```

### Highscore table query

I am using a query found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135081/get-top-scorers-in-mysql) post to gather results for my high-score table:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM users AS s
  JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT highscore
      FROM users
      ORDER BY highscore DESC
          LIMIT 3
    ) AS lim
    ON s.highscore = lim.highscore 
ORDER BY s.highscore DESC ;
```

This would return the top 3 results, i.e. the rows containing sam, james and harry.

### Ranking query

I have a separate query for returning the rank of an individual user in the table:

```
SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) AS rank 
FROM users 
WHERE highscore > (SELECT highscore FROM users WHERE name = '$name');
```

Ranks are returned dynamically, rather than stored in a 'rank' column, because they constantly change depending on the highscores of other users.

### Goal

I would like to merge the ranking query into the highscore table query, so that each row in the `$result` contains something along the lines of: `...,"rank":"(users rank)"`. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want something like this

```
userid  name    highscore   rank
3       harry   46          1
1       james   39          2
0       sam     20          3
```

you can use following query

```
SELECT s.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM users AS s
JOIN
( SELECT DISTINCT highscore
  FROM users
  ORDER BY highscore DESC
      LIMIT 3
) AS lim
ON s.highscore = lim.highscore 
, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY s.highscore DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for